# Dialog close remembers all data

Tags: jquery, dialog

Im using a jQuery dialog i put a trigger on the close  section whenever it is closed it must return the data.

But now this function is remembering old data and put the old data also in console.log. How can i make it that the old data will be forgotten ?

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function() {
    console.log(data);          
});
```

Now the data spits out

1st time:
Test

Second time: 
Test, New Data

3th time
Test, New Data, 3th Data

If i use it without the `click()` function than it throws 1 data out.

Comment: Can you please add the code that's actually adding to data. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: Its a color picker, so everytime it send HEX codes

Comment: post the actual code

Comment: I see--you just want to clear the console

Comment: correct, on close i just want the latest data. Don't need the other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you out..

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function() {
    console.log(data);  
    delete data;    
});
```